# Hover não está sendo exibido corretamente

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Eu tenho um `a` sem link, somente para a exibição de informações adicionais, porém ele não está sendo exibido da maneira correta. Eu queria que ele fosse exibido da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém ele está sendo exibido da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo o código `HTML` e `CSS` usados:

**Código `HTML`:**

```
<a class="tooltips"><strong>!</strong><span class="spanTooltips">Ingresse o máximo de informações possíveis para uma entrega acertiva</span></a>
```

**Código `CSS`:**

```
a.tooltips {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff !important;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background: #E7AF19;
    padding: 1px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
a.tooltips span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 8px solid #E7AF19;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
a.tooltips span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 140px;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    background: #E7AF19;
    padding: 5px 0;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
a:hover.tooltips span {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -70px;
    z-index: 999;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'CoHeadlineCorp-Light';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro era somente de `CSS`, fazendo uma simples alteração no código já se resolve o problema. É só mudar de `position: relative` para `position: absolute`, dessa maneira, o problema é solucionado.

**Abaixo, irá somente a alteração feita no código `CSS`:**

```
a.tooltips {
    position: absolute; /* Alteração feita */
    display: inline-block !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff !important;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background: #E7AF19;
    padding: 1px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione aqui o z-index:

```
a.tooltips {
    z-index: 9999;
    ...
```

Funciona desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não funcionou, continua da mesma maneira.

Comment: Aquela linha cinza do lado direito é o scroll do navegador?

Comment: Não, seria a borda de uma `div`.

Comment: Você tem o link do site? Porque o problema não esta no código do tooltips, veja como ele abre normal: https://jsfiddle.net/d1g1nd6s/1/

Comment: O que eu acho estranho, é que eu tenho outro tooltips um pouco mais em cima deste e ele funciona normalmente, utilizando o mesmo código `CSS`, porém este que está na pergunta fica com esse problema.

Comment: Você já tentou usar o inspetor de elemento naquela parte branca?

Comment: Sim, na parte branca existe um `padding`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67201/discussion-between-wictor-chaves-and-matheus-portela).